# Could you share the procedure to write Magento certification in exam center?

Tags: discussion, magento2

I am planning to take magento2 exam in exam center. Could you share the procedure to write Magento certification in exam center?

Comment: take the print out of all the pdf and payment recipt, and apart from that carry a govt approved id proof which has photograph and signature over it.

Answer (score 4):

> AD0-E711 Adobe Commerce Developer Professional

In the below link, you can find the exam title,syllabus, requirements & benefits of having this certifications.

[Adobe- ADO-E711 Adobe Commerce Developer Professional](https://express.adobe.com/page/saM506xrYKi0p/)
In that page you can find the button named "Register Now", following the link you'll be re-directed to the https://www.certmetrics.com/adobe/ site.

The exam ADO-E702 had the PSI - Proctored Exam (Test Center, Online)
but for the latest syllabus AD0-E711 Adobe Commerce Developer Professional they've removed PSI - Proctored Exam (Test Center, Online) exams.

the [www.certmetrics.com](https://www.certmetrics.com/adobe/) site holds all your data about the exam. Please refer to the attached image.

but for the other old exam the PSI is available.

[image]